# Python: Explode columns into list and eliminate duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below dataframe:

```
st = {"name": ['a', 'a||b||c','a||b||c', 'a||c', 'b', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(st)

name
a||b||c
a||b||c
a||c
b
c
```

I need to get a list of different attribute values, so I expect a list or set that has `a, b, c`. I am thinking about using `explode` function but it does not eliminate duplicates. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have method chain `explode` with `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['attr'].str.split('\|\|').explode().drop_duplicates()

0    a
0    b
0    c
Name: attr, dtype: object
```

Or `explode` with `unique`:

```
df['attr'].str.split('\|\|').explode().unique()

array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```